# App.config acts different than the regular way

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, app-config

My connection string used to be like this:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=G:\I.S\C#\billingSystem\Store.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

so i can (insert, update, delete) with this:

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SQLSTATEMENT", cn);
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
```

I've seen a tutorial on youtube called "Deploy C# Project", when he used

```
System.Configuration;
```

and the `app.config` file, so I followed the tutorial exact the same way and it works.

The problem that after I (insert, update, delete) at runtime everything is okay until I close the application it's like I've did nothing at all the data that I've inserted is gone!.

I need to save the changes into the table at runtime.

Some info: Winforms app, sample from my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SchoolProjectConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\SchoolDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

namespace SchoolProject
{
    public partial class Main : Form
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolProjectConnectionString"].ToString());
        public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myValue = Interaction.InputBox("Enter ID", "ID", "", 100, 100);
            string myValue0 = Interaction.InputBox("Enter Name", "Name", "", 100, 100);
            int X = Convert.ToInt32(myValue);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Student(ID, Student) Values ('" + X + "','" + myValue0 + "')", cn);
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string myValue3 = Interaction.InputBox("Enter ID", "ID", "", 100, 100);
            int X = Convert.ToInt32(myValue3);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE id = '" + X + "'", cn);
            cn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader["Student"].ToString());
                }
            }
            cn.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Report R = new Report();
            R.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unlikely that the connection string, or app.config, "behaves" differently in your Visual Studio debugger than in your runtime. Unless you specify explicity use [XDT transformations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx). Please add the contents of your app.config to the question; if you don't get any errors in your project, but it does seem to work, you might be talking to a different database?

Comment: Check your Project, is the Db visible in the Solution Expl and does it have CopyLocal=true ?

Comment: yes its visible , how to know if it have CopyLocal=true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole *User Instance and AttachDbFileName=* approach is flawed - at best! When running your app in Visual Studio, it will be copying around the `.mdf` file (from your `App_Data` directory to the output directory - typically `.\bin\debug` - where you app runs) and **most likely**, your `INSERT` works just fine - but you're just looking at the **wrong .mdf file** in the end!

If you want to stick with this approach, then try putting a breakpoint on the `myConnection.Close()` call - and then inspect the `.mdf` file with SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express - I'm almost certain your data is there.

The **real solution** in my opinion would be to

1. install SQL Server Express (and you've already done that anyway)
2. install SQL Server Management Studio Express
3. create your database in **SSMS Express**, give it a logical name (e.g. `Store`)
4. connect to it using its logical **database name** (given when you create it on the server) - and don't mess around with physical database files and user instances. In that case, your connection string would be something like:

   ```
   Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Store;Integrated Security=True
   ```

   and everything else is **exactly** the same as before...

Also: you should read up on **SQL injection** and change your code to **avoid** that - it's the #1 security risk for apps. You should use **parametrized queries** in ADO.NET instead - those are safe, and they're faster, too!

Comment: Thanq for answer, yes it seems that the .mdf in the .\bin\debug has all the data, but i cant get it or view it (see button2 in my code), and the second approach i actually don't like to install SSMS because it require me to present physically in the client place ,instead i want just send the package.